# HTML/CSS: how to position forms?

Tags: html, css

I have two forms on one web page and both of them function properly. Because of the sequence of the HTML code of the two forms, the second form is below the first. I would like to place them side by side, or more generally, at desirable positions. How can I control the positions of forms? Can anyone help? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Use CSS to set the position.

Comment: With [Cascading Style Sheets (CSS)..](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cascading_Style_Sheets)

Comment: Using ccs, for example -> `<style> form {width:50%; float:left;} </style>`

Comment: _To drive a car you first need a driving licence._

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the CSS [`float`](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_float.asp):

```
#form1{
    width: 50%; // so that the other form will have space
    float: left; // stick to the left
}
#form2{
    width: 50%;
    float: right;
}
```

You can also play with the widths and lower them, and the 2 forms will still stick to left, and right respectively.

Comment: We shouldn't spoon-feed people here.

Comment: Yeah, I guess you're right, but it would have been rude of me to just post the link to the `float` docs, right?

Comment: I honestly wouldn't post anything. The question is clearly out of SO scope/policy/rules/recommendations.